# jQuery jsonP response headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Does anyone know how I might get the headers from the response of a jsonp request? The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) don't mention specifically that this isn't supported, but `getReponseHeader` always returns `null` for the header I'm interested in. Is it not possible to get the headers for a request when the response is a script?

Google Chrome shows the header coming back with the response, but I just can't grab it from the jqXHR object.

Comment: Any chance that the header you are interested in shows up in `getAllResponseHeaders()` ?

Comment: it does not, that just returns an empty string. Looks like, according to @Femi, it just isn't possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately not: given that the request is executed using a `<script>` tag, the browser generally won't give access to any of the headers from JavaScript. The jqXHR object created by jQuery doesn't have any way to extract those headers as the request technically doesn't come from it.

Comment: that's what I was worried about. It's a shame since the browser recognizes that headers are being sent back...