# jQuery jsonP response headers validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jsonp

I'm accessing an external API through JSONP and I need to verify the content type of the response to make sure it's "text/html".

In the following discussion ([jQuery jsonP response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408569/jquery-jsonp-response-headers)) Femi says "given that the request is executed using a  tag, the browser generally won't give access to any of the headers from JavaScript".

Does it mean there's no way to validate the response? Any alternative suggestions on how this validation can be achieved.

Comment: Why would the content type of a jsonp response be text/html?

Comment: The content-type of a JSONP response should be `application/javascript`.  When you make a JSONP call, a `<script>` tag is added to your page and executed.  There are no headers you can access.

Comment: Thanks Rocket Hazmat and Jason P. Yes, I'm aware a jsonp response is actually "application/javascript" but I'm receiving it as "text/html" because that's how the API sends it (out of my control). Still, there's a security panel that requested me to confirm the response is "text/html" so they can approve it. Once I won't be able to provide that confirmation, I would like to give them online documentation that supports the knowledge that I won't be able to provide this validation. Would you be able to point me to where to find documentation for that? Many thanks.